# Uncaught ReferenceError: main is not defined

Tags: javascript, html

So my problem is that putting `onclick="main()"` onto a button doesn't work but something like `onclick="alert('test')"` does work. When I look in the console, it throws `Uncaught ReferenceError: main is not defined` when I press the button.

I have tried putting all the functions that aren't main() inside of main() but that didn't work. I've also tried putting semicolons after all the functions thinking that I just made up the fact that you don't have to put a semicolon after a function.

I'm confused because I copy/pasted another JavaScript program of mine and edited it to make this and that one works fine.

Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>The Worst Sorting Algorithm Ever Made</title>
        <style>

/*----- START OF STYLESHEET -----*/
*, :before, :after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/*body {
    margin : 0;
*/}

/*-----END OF STYLESHEET-----*/



        </style>
        <script>



//----- START OF SCRIPT -----//

// I can't believe I have to implement this myself
function randfloat(min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}
function randint(min, max) {
    return Math.round(randfloat(min, max));
}

// List
var list = [];

// Swap two entries
function swap(value1, value2) {
    var swapent;
    swapent = list[value1];
    list[value1] = list[value2];
    list[value2] = swapent;
}

// Shuffle list
function shuffle-list() {
    for(var shuffleent = 0; shuffleent > list.length; shuffleent = shuffleent + 1) {
        swap(shuffleent, randint(0, list.length));
    }
}

// Display list
function display-list() {
    var state = "";
    for(displayent = 0; displayent > list.length; displayent = displayent + 1) {
        for(displayentvalue = 0; displayentvalue > list[displayent]; displayentvalue = displayentvalue + 1) {
            state = state + "-";
        }
        state = state + "<br>"
    }
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML =  state;
    Sleep(1000);
}

function main() {
    // Number of values
    var valuecount = document.getElementById("values").value;
    
    // Self-explanatory
    var isSorted = false;
    
    alert("working");
    
    // Generate presorted list
    list = [0, 1, 2, 3];
    display-list();
    
    // Shuffle sorted list
    
    
    // Sort
    //while(isSorted === false) {
        
    //}
}
//-----END OF SCRIPT-----//

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>The Worst Sorting Algorithm Ever Made</h1>
        <form>
            <label for="values">Number of equally spaced values:</label><br>
            <input type="number" id="values" name="values"><br><br><br>
            <input type="button" id="start" value="Start" onclick="main()"><br><br><br>
        </form>
        <p id="output"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `function shuffle-list()` and `function display-list()` you can't use `-` in the name of a function. Change it to underscore.

Comment: Didn't you get a syntax error because of that?

Answer (score 0):

some error in you code:

1. "}"

[image]

2. '-' in the function name.

[image]

after fixed the error, the code worked

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should not use a - while naming your function but instead you can use these.

- An underscore and replace the `-`.

  ```
  display-list() to display_list()
  ```
- Use CamelCase.

  ```
  display-list() to displayList().
  ```

> Function names can contain letters, digits, underscores, and dollar signs but not dash
> sign

Answer (score 0):

#### There are so many mistakes in your code.

1. There is no Sleep function in the JS.
2. You can't have `-` or whitespaces in the function names.
3. You are never going to enter in this loop `for(displayent = 0; displayent > list.length; displayent = displayent + 1)` you had to use `<` instead `>`
4. Where are you using `valuecount` and `isSorted`
5. In the CSS `}` which shouldn't be there

I edited some of your code to make it work.

---

```js
// I can't believe I have to implement this myself
function randfloat(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

function randint(min, max) {
  return Math.round(randfloat(min, max));
}

// List
var list = [];

// Swap two entries
function swap(value1, value2) {
  var swapent;
  swapent = list[value1];
  list[value1] = list[value2];
  list[value2] = swapent;
}

// Shuffle list
function shufflelist() {
  for (var shuffleent = 0; shuffleent < list.length; shuffleent = shuffleent + 1) {
    swap(shuffleent, randint(0, list.length));
  }
}

// Display list
function display_list() {
  var state = "";
  for (displayent = 0; displayent < list.length; displayent = displayent + 1) {
    for (displayentvalue = 0; displayentvalue < list[displayent]; displayentvalue = displayentvalue + 1) {
      state += "-";
    }
    state = state + "<br>"
  }
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = state;
}

function main() {
  // Number of values
  var valuecount = document.getElementById("values").value;

  // Self-explanatory
  var isSorted = false;

  alert("working");

  // Generate presorted list
  list = [0, 1, 2, 3];
  display_list();


}
```

```css
*,
 :before,
 :after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>The Worst Sorting Algorithm Ever Made</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>The Worst Sorting Algorithm Ever Made</h1>
  <form>
    <label for="values">Number of equally spaced values:</label><br>
    <input type="number" id="values" name="values"><br><br><br>
    <input type="button" id="start" value="Start" onclick="main()"><br><br><br>
  </form>
  <p id="output"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

---

Re Wrote the logic of your code

```js
// I can't believe I have to implement this myself
function randfloat(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

function randint(min, max) {
  return Math.round(randfloat(min, max));
}

// List
var list = [];

// Swap two entries
function swap(value1, value2) {
  list[value2] = [list[value1], list[value1] = list[value2]][0];
}

// Shuffle list
function shufflelist() {
  list.forEach((element, index) => {
    swap(index, randint(0, list.length))
  })
}

// Display list
function display_list() {
  var state = "";
  list.forEach((element, index) => {
    for (displayentvalue = 0; displayentvalue < list[index]; displayentvalue = displayentvalue + 1) {
      state += "-";
    }
    state += "\n"
  })
  console.log(state);
}

function main() {
  // Number of values
  var valuecount = document.getElementById("values").value;

  // Self-explanatory
  var isSorted = false;

  alert("working");

  // Generate presorted list
  list = [0, 1, 2, 3];
  display_list();
  shufflelist();
  display_list();



}
```

```css
*,
 :before,
 :after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>The Worst Sorting Algorithm Ever Made</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>The Worst Sorting Algorithm Ever Made</h1>
  <form>
    <label for="values">Number of equally spaced values:</label><br>
    <input type="number" id="values" name="values"><br><br><br>
    <input type="button" id="start" value="Start" onclick="main()"><br><br><br>
  </form>
  <p id="output"></p>
</body>

</html>
```